# Is this equality correct in Edwards's proof of the uniform convergence of a sequence of a function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, calculus-of-variations

This question regards [Advanced Calculus of Several Variables, by C.H. Edwards, Jr.](https://books.google.com/books/about/Advanced_Calculus_of_Several_Variables.html?id=sZIFcJ8DJAIC&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button#v=onepage&q&f=false)

> Theorem VI.1.4 Let $\left\{ f_{n}\right\} _{1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence
>   of continuously differentiable real-valued functions on $\left[a,b\right],$
>   converging (pointwise) to $f$. Suppose that the $\left\{ f_{n}^{\prime}\right\} _{1}^{\infty}$
>   converges uniformily to $g$. Then $\left\{ f_{n}\right\} _{1}^{\infty}$
>   converges uniformly to $f,$ and $f$ is differentiable, with $f^{\prime}=g$.
>
> PROOF By the fundamental theorem of calculus, we have
>
> $$
> f_{n}\left[x\right]=f_{n}\left[a\right]+\int_{a}^{x}f_{n}^{\prime}
> $$
>   for each $n$ and each $x\in\left[a,b\right]$. From this and Exercise
>   IV.3.4 (on the termwise integration of a uniformly convergent sequence
>   of continuous functions) we obtain
>
> $$
> f\left[x\right]=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_{n}\left[x\right]
> $$
>
> $$
> =\lim_{n\to\infty}f_{n}\left[a\right]+\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{a}^{x}f_{n}^{\prime},
> $$
>
> $$
> f\left[x\right]=f\left[a\right]+\int_{a}^{x}g.
> $$
>   Another application of the fundamental theorem yields $f^{\prime}=g$
>   as desired.
>
> To see that the convergence of $\left\{ f_{n}\right\} _{1}^{\infty}$
>   to $f$ is uniform, note that
>
> $$
> \left|f_{n}\left[x\right]-f\left[x\right]\right|=\left|\int_{a}^{x}f_{n}^{\prime}-\int_{a}^{x}g\right|+\left|f_{n}\left[a\right]-f\left[a\right]\right|
> $$
>
> $$
> \le\int_{a}^{x}\left|f_{n}^{\prime}-g\right|+\left|f_{n}\left[a\right]-f\left[a\right]\right|
> $$
>
> $$
> \le\left(b-a\right)\left\Vert f_{n}^{\prime}-g\right\Vert _{0}+\left|f_{n}\left[a\right]-f\left[a\right]\right|.
> $$
>   The uniform convergence of the sequence $\left\{ f_{n}\right\} _{1}^{\infty}$
>   therefore follows from that of the sequence $\left\{ f_{n}^{\prime}\right\} _{1}^{\infty}$.

I do not see how the equivalence

$$
\left|f_{n}\left[x\right]-f\left[x\right]\right|=\left|\int_{a}^{x}f_{n}^{\prime}-\int_{a}^{x}g\right|+\left|f_{n}\left[a\right]-f\left[a\right]\right|
$$
is justified. The equation 
$$
f_{n}\left[x\right]-f\left[x\right]=\int_{a}^{x}f_{n}^{\prime}+f_{n}\left[a\right]-\left(\int_{a}^{x}g+f\left[a\right]\right)
$$

$$
=\int_{a}^{x}f_{n}^{\prime}-\int_{a}^{x}g+f_{n}\left[a\right]-f\left[a\right]
$$
is clearly valid. But the triangle inequality gives
$$
\left|\left(\int_{a}^{x}f_{n}^{\prime}-\int_{a}^{x}g\right)+\left(f_{n}\left[a\right]-f\left[a\right]\right)\right|\le\left|\int_{a}^{x}f_{n}^{\prime}-\int_{a}^{x}g\right|+\left|f_{n}\left[a\right]-f\left[a\right]\right|.
$$

I can think of no reason why the functions $f_n$, $f$ and their derivatives
cannot, in general, change signs, or have their differences change signs on the interval $\left[a,b\right]$.

**Is Edwards's statement of the proof correct?**

Comment: Typo, it should be $\leqslant$ as you say.

Comment: If you turn that into an answer, I will be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a typo. As you say, it ought to be "$\leqslant$".